# Looping through a multiple value parameter array

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a parameter that allows multiple values. Its for a name field in my database. What I want to be able to do is allow the user to put in a name and then have crystal find any name like any of the names they entered. So for example you could put in 4 last names and crystal would return anyone who had any of those names in the name field. I can get the "like" to work just fine, but only when there is one string in the array. Here is my select formula:

```
    numbervar counter := 1;
    numbervar positionCount:=count({?Customer Name}); //I'm not sure what to put
                                                        here. Count? UBound? 

    if {?Customer Name}[1] <> 'ALL'
    then
    (
         while(counter <= positionCount)
         do
         (       
            {NAMEFIELD} like  '*' & {?Customer Name}[counter] & '*';
            counter := counter + 1;
         );
    ) 
    else
    if {?Customer Name}[1] = 'ALL'
    then
    true
    )
```

This formula returns all of the names, not the ones in the parameter. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a multi-value parameter ({?Customer Name}) with these properties:

- Default Value: ALL
- All multiple values: TRUE

Add a row to the parameter's pick-list grid; supply 'ALL' and 'ALL' (without single quotes)

Create a Custom Function (named 'Delimit') with this text:

```
// Delimit()
// enclose each value in array in **, returning an array
Function (Stringvar Array params)

  Split("*" + Join(params, "*,*") + "*", ",")
```

Modify the report's record-selection formula:

```
If {?Customer Name}<>"ALL" Then
    {TABLE.CUSTOMER_NAME} LIKE Delimit({?Customer Name})
Else
    True
```

Optionally, create a formula to display the parameter's values with this text:

```
//{@Customer Name}
Join( Delimit({?Customer Name}), ";")
```

Answer (score 2):

Luckily CR can handle this situation automatically (at least in CR2008, where I just confirmed it). You can just do `{?Customer Name}="All" or {NAMEFIELD} like {?Customer Name}`.

It will be up to the end user to use the wild cards appropriately, but you can add a blurb to the parameter's help text or force the *Name* format with an edit mask.

Comment: What Ryan says is correct, or you could of course do `{?Customer Name}="All" or {NAMEFIELD} like '*' + {?Customer Name} + '*'` so the user doesn't have to enter the wildcard :)

Comment: @LeeTickett Despite seeming correct, that actually won't work. The '+' operator works differently on string arrays than they do on strings. It is basically treating the two '*' strings as additional entries in the array, so you'll match every record. If you try using the '&' concatenation operator in the same way, CR will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (I thought it made sense to create a separate answer), if you have Oracle, is to make use of the [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) expression.

- Create a report that uses a Command.
- Create a string parameter ({?QUERY}) in the Command's panel; set the default value to 'ALL' (without single quotes).
- Add the query to the Command; reference the parameter:

`SELECT customer_name FROM customers WHERE ( '{?QUERY}'='ALL' OR REGEXP_LIKE(customer_name, '{?QUERY}') )`

- Add fields to the report as usual
- When prompted (running the report), enter a regular expression in the QUERY parameter.  The pattern `'A|B|C'` is equivalent to `LIKE '%A%' OR LIKE '%B%' OR LIKE '%C%'`.