# How to use multi-value parameters in selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working in a crystal report and want to create a parameter that lets users enter multiple strings to search for.

For example, when I enter the search terms "hammer", "wax", and "mask" I need get all the records that include any of these three words.

I am trying to use wildcards, like this:

```
(if {?DescWildcard} <> 'x' then lowercase({POIT.Description}) like '*' & lowercase({?DescWildcard}) & '*' else 1=1)
```

But, it only works with one keyword.

How can I deal with multiple values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the thread here: [Looping through a multiple value parameter array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093544/looping-through-a-multiple-value-parameter-array)

Working with a multi-value parameter is made a little harder when you want to do text searching because the addition of wildcards can be a little tricky.

The accepted answer in that thread will automatically surround your keywords with wildcards so you'd be free to do something like:

```
{?DescWildcard} = 'x' or lowercase({POIT.Description}) like delimit({?DescWildcard})
```

Comment: @user1723572 Awesome. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote the useful answers in the linked thread that you found helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user, How can i acceept the answer and upvote?:)

Comment: @user1723572 Click the checkmark to accept an answer, and click the up arrow/triangle to upvote. [FAQ; How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: thanks, I accept the answer but do not enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: when i try this code serveral times,  i find some problems. I can can only put two key words each time, and if I put more key words rather than i get more records i got less. It does not sound right.

Comment: @user1723572 What, exactly, did you try (include code where it's appropriate)? Can you clarify what you mean by "I can only put two key words..."?

Comment: sorry for that .For example, In my DescWildcard parameter, I put 'wax, masks', I want to get all the record have these two key words. i put code like these:  AND (if {?DescWildcard} <> 'x' then lowercase({POIT.Description}) like delimit((lowercase({?DescWildcard}))else 1=1) thanks

Comment: I also try something like these :   
AND (if {?DescWildcard} <> 'x' then lowercase({POIT.Description}) in (split(/,/,(lowercase({?DescWildcard}))))
   else 1=1)   it is not work either

Comment: @user1723572 Your parameter needs to be set to "Allow Multiple Values", you can't just pass in a single string like "wax, masks". My suggestion is that you read up a little on how to use parameters in this way and also how to work with string arrays. Good luck.

Comment: @Ryan: +1 for referencing my answer.