# Create Crystal Report Variables from Detail

Tags: variables, crystal-reports

I have a problem with reports and subreports.

I would post a screen shot but not got enough reputation.

I have added the screen shot as my profile picture.

In the example the order number is derived from the PO and the number of lines and order number varies for each PO.

I want to be able to capture the Order Number as a variable for each detail row to be able to pass this variable to another report.

The reason for this is i need to use the order no to select data in another report.

I can capture the range of order numbers using minimum and maximum in a formula, but there are a lot of order numbers between the min and max that are not required. I only need the numbers shown in the primary report.

I hope that this makes sense.

Regards,
Alec

Comment: I didn't get if you want to create a subreport for each detail, but in this case give a look a t this link, it shows how to link fields between the main report and the sub report, http://scn.sap.com/people/prabhat.kumar2/blog/2011/11/06/passing-values-between-reports-in-crystal-reports-2008

Comment: Sorry for maybe not explaining well enough. Subreport1 provides me with a list of Order numbers. I need subreport2 to use only the numbers shown in subreport1.

Comment: I am wondering if something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093544/looping-through-a-multiple-value-parameter-array would assist, but configured for numbervar not stringcar

Comment: It could work you have to try it, I was googling and found a similar post, I've never done something like this, I usually try to solve most part of the filtering directly on the queries.

Comment: can you elaborate more on primary report? Also confirm you need to pass every value in the detail to sub report?

Comment: Siva, the primary report shows the PO Number and Order Number. It is the order number that i need to capture and pass into a secondary report which uses that number to display further information. I can not simply show the field i need on the first report due to the grouping on each of the reports to show the correct information.

Comment: I have managed to upload a screen shot of what the report looks like. There are two seperate reports and what i need is the list on the right in subreport 2 to only show the values that match the ordernumber in the left report(subreport1).

http://tinypic.com/r/2ln7og7/8